# Configuring EDI Validation by Message Type

Tags: azure-logic-apps, edi

In a Logic Apps workflow, I am working with a customer on an 856 that does not require segment PRF, element 1 which is otherwise required. I have found out how to set up the Agreement's receive settings to skip enough of the 856 validations to allow it through.

[image]

However, I figure this suppresses validation I do want. Is it possible to do something more fine-grained in the validation? For instance, can I configure a 856 message type that is just like industry standard 856, save the requirement of this one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation settings in the Agreement only cover a few global settings, like leading and trailing spaces.

You can fully customize any specific transaction by modifying it's schema before uploading to you IA.

In this case, open the 865 Schema in Visual Studio and do two things:

1. On the `<Schema>` node, **change Target Namespace** to something you app owns, like uri:MyApp.  This is to differentiate it from the default schemas.
2. Navigate to PRF under HLLoop1.  **Set Max Occurs to 0**.  The default (blank) is 1.

Replace the Schema in the Integration Account and PRF will no longer be required when 856 is received for this Agreement.

Comment: I had previously tried the altered XSD but didn't know to change Target Namespace. I like the idea of this approach, but I am not finding it working. The IA refused the upload with: "The provided schema content is not valid. If the schema has any references, please upload the referenced schemas to the Integration Account first. The compilation of schema failed with error: 'Type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006:X12_ID_128' is not declared.'."

Comment: @TomSchulte Bah, stupid Markdown!  You change the "Target namespace" property on the **<Schema>** node.  Edited.

Comment: Not sure what would be a Namespace for "something my app owns" (Isn't "my app" the Logic Apps Workflow in this case?) Either way, whatever I tried ended up not uploading with the IA returning the error: "The provided schema content is not valid. If the schema has any references, please upload the referenced schemas to the Integration Account first. The compilation of schema failed with error: 'Type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006:X12_ID_128' is not declared.'." So, I just left the Target Namespace as-is and used a new name for a copy of the XSD and it is working.

Comment: I should add, that I don't haven't working at the Agreement level, instead I am just using an XML Validation action on the decoded payload property of the Decode action output. Maybe not as elegant as I wanted, but it will get the job done.